# Payment with ePay PHP API

Tags: php, soap

In the last one week and a half, I've been looking for an answer on the question: how do I get my payment API to work?

I have a test account with the Danish payment gateway provider ePay/Bambora.

I have no problem getting the JavaScript version to Work, but I'd like to do the payment by an PHP-api, to make sure I have full control on which information is hidden for people who don't need to see it, information such as my "MerchantID".

ePay/Bambora seems to be very scarce with their information on how to fulfill a payment by PHP, or else I might be blind (or can't see the forest before the trees).

This is the code I've been written:

```js
<?php
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = "1234567"; //fake ID
$epay_params['transactionid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['amount'] = "9995";
$epay_params['group'] = "-1";
$epay_params['paymentcollection'] = "1";
$epay_params['orderid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['pbsResponse'] = "-1";
$epay_params['epayresponse'] = "-1";
$client = new SoapClient('https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx?WSDL');
$result = $client->capture($epay_params);
if($result->captureResult == true){ 
    echo "Result OK";  //Capture OK 
} 
else{ 
    echo json_encode( $result );
}
?>
```

This gives the following result: `{"captureResult":false,"pbsResponse":-1,"epayresponse":-1008}`

According to ePay/Bambora does -1008 mean, that the transactionid isn't found.

This seems to be correct, since there is no transaction called -1. I want to create a NEW payment, so I don't have a transaction id yet.

So either I have to create a transactionid on ePay/Bamboras server BEFORE I run the payment (how?) or I should not use the method "capture", but which method should I use then?

To be clear: I am not making a webshop, but just a payment system on my new calendar webapp.

> **The Question is:** How do I fulfill a single payment via ePay/Bambora in PHP?

Comment: Thanks, Cooper, for correcting my grammatical flaws. I surely will learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `http_build_query()` for make URL perfectly

```
<?php
$url = 'https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx';
$params = array('WSDL');
$url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = "1234567"; //fake ID
$epay_params['transactionid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['amount'] = "9995";
$epay_params['group'] = "-1";
$epay_params['paymentcollection'] = "1";
$epay_params['orderid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['pbsResponse'] = "-1";
$epay_params['epayresponse'] = "-1";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $client->capture($epay_params);
if($result->captureResult == true){ 
    echo "Result OK";  //Capture OK 
} 
else{ 
    echo json_encode( $result );
}
?>
```

Hope this work either knock me

Comment: Thanks MD. Jubair Mizan. I am not familiar with http_build_query. The script throws an error:
Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\kairosplanner.local\api\payment.php on line 51
This seems to me rubbish, but that might be because I don't know http_build_query :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake i have update my code please look ahead with this i have make a new variable call `params` and call it inside `http_build_query()`

Comment: This results in an error from the remote server: Seems like the url changes to https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx?0=WSDL in stead of https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/payment.asmx?WSDL